# Python Tkinter updating text-box content via a function

Tags: python, tkinter

Beginner programmer here, working on making a basic GUI as part of a tutorial I was following online, but none of them say how to get a Text box to update using the output of the other parts of your code.

I tried multiple other answers on the site, including one using StringVar's, which got me nowhere, another using a decorator, and the rest seemed way out of my depth.

Here's my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

import time
#Creating Root
root = tk.Tk()


#GUI TEMPLATE


frame =tk.Frame(root,
            height = 100,
            width = 400)
frame.pack()
v = StringVar()

colour = ["red","blue","green","white","yellow"]
labels = range(5) 
#change number to change how many labels
for i in range(5):
    l= tk.Label(root,
            text = colour[i],
            bg = colour[i])
    l.place(x = 10 +i*70, y = 10, width=60, height=25)




T1 = tk.Text(root, height=2, width=40)
words = "Don't name your files after module names!"
T1.insert(tk.END, textvariable=v)

T1.place(x = 10, y= 40)

S = tk.Scrollbar(root)
S.config(command=T1.yview)
S.place(x = 340, y=40)

T1.config(yscrollcommand=S.set)

root.mainloop()

v.set("Something Else!")
```

Now, what it should output is a row of coloured labels, which works fine, and a text box with a scroll bar, which should instantly update to read 'Something Else!', which does not work fine.

Instead I get the following error:

NameError: name 'StringVar' is not defined

I know what this error means, it's just I've hit a wall when it comes to finding a solution that works for me, and doesn't need a doctorate to understand.

What I'm asking for is if someone can give me a solution that would work for this, and hopefully explain it!

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
So after fixing the syntax error, and then finding out what I'm trying to do doesn't work, how would I go about this?

Could I use a label instead? Or is there another, better way? 
Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StringVar` should accessed via `tk`:

```
v = tk.StringVar()
```

On another note, `tk.Text.insert` does not take a `textvariable` parameter, so the following won't work:

```
T1.insert(tk.END, textvariable=v)
#                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^??
```

From the [docs](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/text.html):

> Unlike for example the entry widget, text widgets don't support a
>   "textvariable" configuration option

Also see [How can I connect a StringVar to a Text widget in Python/Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593027/how-can-i-connect-a-stringvar-to-a-text-widget-in-python-tkinter) as to why this won't work.

Comment: Thank you! I never thought to try and access it via tk. As for the second part, how do text variables work? I couldn't find much online, sorry to ask another question!

Answer (score 1):

I was experimenting with learning threading with Tkinter and have made something work to insert and update text in a Tkinter text box in Python3 which may be of help.

I found that by deleting the text I could then insert new text.  Untill I deleted the existing text the instruction to insert text seamed to be ignored.

```
{  foo = input("Give me input: " )
   self.T.delete("1.0", END)   #Clear the text window so we can write.
   self.T.insert(END,foo)      #Write the new text.}
```

Comment: I tried to post my entire file but the formatting was a mess.